# Android RoboSpice cache managment and offline mode

Tags: android, android-networking, robospice

I'm planning to to use RoboSpice + OrmLite for data caching and I want my app to work offline and use cached data. I'm new to RoboSpice.

I want to implement following case:
if user has an internet connection data each time is requested from server (because it can be changed) and cached in db
if user don't have an internet connection data should be taken from db and never expire.

```
getSpiceManager().execute(weatherRequest, new Integer(0), DurationInMillis.ALWAYS_RETURNED, new WeatherRequestListener());
```

If I understand right `DurationInMillis.ALWAYS_RETURNED` means that data will be loaded once and other times loaded from cache. If there any options to implement described scenario?

I see something like `NetworkStateChecker` and it can be overriden in SpiceService. Maybe it is the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `SpiceManager#getFromCacheAndLoadFromNetworkIfExpired`. From the javadoc:

> Gets data from cache, expired or not, and executes a request normaly. Before invoking the method `SpiceRequest.loadDataFromNetwork()`, the cache will be checked : if a result has been cached with the cache key `requestCacheKey`, RoboSpice will consider the parameter `cacheExpiryDuration` to determine whether the result in the cache is expired or not. If it is not expired, then listeners will receive the data in cache only. If the result is absent or expired, then `SpiceRequest.loadDataFromNetwork()` will be invoked and the result will be stored in cache using the cache key `requestCacheKey`.

It doesn't explain it completely, but when the cache is expired you will get a result from there nonetheless. Then, if you have used `DurationInMillis.ALWAYS_EXPIRED`, the cache is going to be refreshed from network each time. So you will be able to get the fresh data from network only in an additional request.

Another approach for you would be to implement `RequestListener#onRequestFailure` to load data from cache using `SpiceManager#getDataFromCache`. Please note that you will probably want to implement a custom `com.octo.android.robospice.retry.RetryPolicy` in this case.

Finally, the `NetworkStateChecker` is not reliable to the extent of knowing if the internet connection is actually working, so your best bet in both cases would be to just try executing the request every time you need data.